# RingCentral: After successfully making a new subscription, there is no webhook posted while the RingOut call is in progress

Tags: api, webhooks, subscription, ringcentral, ringout

Yesterday, I found a problem that after successfully making a new subscription, there is no webhook posted to the specified URL while the RingOut call is in progress.

So far, when my app subscribes for the events (mentioned below), I see that the whole process go through just fine and my webhook endpoint always gets something back from RingCentral. However, after that, there is ZERO postback to that webhook endpoint so far.

The webhook endpoint is always accessible and operational without issue.

At the moment, I believe that there is no postback from RingCentral but I am not so sure about that.

I would like some guidance how to investigate this issue.

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

1. Make a new subscription or ignore if there is an active **webhook** subscription for the following events:

   - `/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/presence?detailedTelephonyState=true&sipData=true`
   - `/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/presence/line/presence?detailedTelephonyState=true`
2. Make a RingOut call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the same issue as I built out this sample app showing how Webhooks with RingCentral can operate: https://github.com/bdeanindy/ringcentral-webhook-basics

```
> ringcentral-webhook-basics@0.1.0 start /Users/benjamin.dean/MyApps/ringcentral-webhook-basics
> node index.js

PORT:  3000
Server is listening on port:  3000
LOGIN SUCCESS DATA:  { access_token: 'HIDDEN',
  token_type: 'bearer',
  expires_in: 3600,
  refresh_token: 'HIDDEN',
  refresh_token_expires_in: 604800,
  scope: 'ReadMessages Faxes ReadPresence ReadAccounts EditExtensions RingOut SMS InternalMessages ReadCallLog ReadCallRecording Accounts',
  owner_id: 'HIDDEN',
  endpoint_id: 'HIDDEN' }

BODY:  
Subscription Response:  { uri: 'https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/subscription/HIDDEN',
  id: 'HIDDEN',
  creationTime: '2016-09-15T22:48:45.877Z',
  status: 'Active',
  eventFilters: 
   [ '/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension/134694004/presence?detailedTelephonyState=true',
     '/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension/133128004/presence?detailedTelephonyState=true',
     '/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension/664573005/presence?detailedTelephonyState=true',
     '/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension/133165004/presence?detailedTelephonyState=true',
     '/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension/138323004/presence?detailedTelephonyState=true' ],
  expirationTime: '2016-09-22T22:48:45.877Z',
  expiresIn: 604799,
  deliveryMode: 
   { transportType: 'WebHook',
     encryption: false,
     address: 'http://fbe654d0.ngrok.io/webhooks?auth_token=HIDDEN' } }

Just made a call from soft phone to my mobile device (no events are arriving).

Now I am going to hangup the call and then I am going to change the availability status of the user to see if that generates events...    

BODY:  {"uuid":"88474bfa-061e-4184-9e39-3ca78e51e1be","event":"/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension","timestamp":"2016-09-15T22:50:34.418Z","subscriptionId":"ad355889-74cc-4db1-9fd0-fc20f442c261","body":{"extensions":[{"extensionId":"133128004","eventType":"Update"}]}}
BODY:  {"uuid":"bc236a49-e01b-4c3f-bb75-872745381a3b","event":"/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension","timestamp":"2016-09-15T22:50:34.418Z","subscriptionId":"26ba88c0-0554-4ff7-8dfb-e1f597306176","body":{"extensions":[{"extensionId":"133128004","eventType":"Update"}]}}
BODY:  {"uuid":"4efc4740-3b26-43a4-8c74-e984a778c364","event":"/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension","timestamp":"2016-09-15T22:50:34.418Z","subscriptionId":"b2d76ced-b860-4fb9-af1d-aeb55cf2bf0f","body":{"extensions":[{"extensionId":"133128004","eventType":"Update"}]}}
BODY:  {"uuid":"b3d53990-26ae-4241-8eac-0acfe210c6cb","event":"/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension","timestamp":"2016-09-15T22:50:34.418Z","subscriptionId":"f22cec6d-3f0e-4a10-aa6b-e3a726fe8e61","body":{"extensions":[{"extensionId":"133128004","eventType":"Update"}]}}
BODY:  {"uuid":"4a3aebe7-8fd7-411b-8cf6-6809be3491a1","event":"/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension","timestamp":"2016-09-15T22:50:34.418Z","subscriptionId":"9dc0fbd3-b5dc-4b09-9dd1-db61098b6195","body":{"extensions":[{"extensionId":"133128004","eventType":"Update"}]}}
BODY:  {"uuid":"54fe63e4-6cec-4da7-b91b-02066f2218d7","event":"/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension","timestamp":"2016-09-15T22:50:37.431Z","subscriptionId":"ad355889-74cc-4db1-9fd0-fc20f442c261","body":{"extensions":[{"extensionId":"133128004","eventType":"Update"}]}}
BODY:  {"uuid":"3abf1018-816b-48cd-a8b5-eb7c484f25bc","event":"/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension","timestamp":"2016-09-15T22:50:37.431Z","subscriptionId":"26ba88c0-0554-4ff7-8dfb-e1f597306176","body":{"extensions":[{"extensionId":"133128004","eventType":"Update"}]}}
BODY:  {"uuid":"70fba7c1-e820-408c-897f-387d23aad789","event":"/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension","timestamp":"2016-09-15T22:50:37.431Z","subscriptionId":"f22cec6d-3f0e-4a10-aa6b-e3a726fe8e61","body":{"extensions":[{"extensionId":"133128004","eventType":"Update"}]}}
BODY:  {"uuid":"20a4207e-9574-43ad-8246-afb2bb728853","event":"/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension","timestamp":"2016-09-15T22:50:37.431Z","subscriptionId":"b2d76ced-b860-4fb9-af1d-aeb55cf2bf0f","body":{"extensions":[{"extensionId":"133128004","eventType":"Update"}]}}
BODY:  {"uuid":"aa3d2e9f-dde5-4259-b14d-f105056784d1","event":"/restapi/v1.0/account/133128004/extension","timestamp":"2016-09-15T22:50:37.431Z","subscriptionId":"9dc0fbd3-b5dc-4b09-9dd1-db61098b6195","body":{"extensions":[{"extensionId":"133128004","eventType":"Update"}]}}

So we are not receiving any telephony events for VOIP, but we are receiving presence events for the extension.

Now, let's try sending an SMS and see if we receive any events.
Nope, no events for SMS either.
```

I found that no telephony related events were being POSTed to my webhook endpoint as expected, but the extension presence events (updates and modifications to availability) were generating events.

I have contacted our engineering team to investigate this issue and to help get it resolved.

Thank you for reporting this Janielle. I will update this post when it has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this Benjamin, we're all eagerly awaiting an update or resolution to this.

Comment: Our engineering/operations team has informed me this issue has been resolved.

I have confirmed it using the application URL above (which I've made updates to add a Heroku One-Button deployment for easier use) to test.

Everything seems to be back in working order.

Let me know if it is working for you.

Comment: Glad to hear you're back in business. :)